# warning while defining lookup to get single value from a list in workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, filter, workflow-lookup

While assigning value from another list to workflow variable with filter I get an error saying

> "The lookup that you defined is not guaranteed to return a single
>   value. If more than one value is returned, only the first value will
>   be used".

[image]

On click of Ok button I get this error.

[image]

How do I get date from holiday list which is same as current date?

Comment: It's not error message its just a warning.
Go ahead and click on Yes button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a warning

If this is your List, and today = 9-6-2017

[image]

Your Workflow Lookup will return **paul** but NOT ringo